# Traverse an object's properties with dynamic names

Tags: php, object, twitter

I am trying to get the current trends from the twitter api (but that's sorta irrelevant).

I receive the information as an object. In this situation some of the properties that I need to access, are dates from when the trends were last updated, therefore I can't hard code the property names.

Here's an example incase I didn't explain myself well, which I fear I didn't :(

```
stdClass Object
(
[2011-03-09 02:45] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [promoted_content] => 
                [events] => 
                [query] => RIP Mike Starr
                [name] => RIP Mike Starr
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [promoted_content] => 
                [events] => 
                [query] => Mac & Cheese
                [name] => Mac & Cheese
            )
```

Note: This is not the full object

Comment: You can simply foreach over object properties. Use that in hierarchy levels which you do not care about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can traverse an object's properties using [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get_object_vars)

```
$fooBar = new stdClass();
$fooBar->apple = 'red';
$fooBar->pear  = 'green';

foreach(get_object_vars($fooBar) as $property => $value) {
  echo $property . " = " . $value . "\n";
}

// Output
// apple = red
// pear = green
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you getting this data as JSON?  If so, check out [the second argument to `json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which lets you get the results back as an associative array instead of as an object.  This will let you use the normal loop constructs, like `foreach` and obtain keys using `array_keys`.

If you aren't getting this data via JSON, you can consider using [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to grab [the properties of an object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php).  (edit #2: I'm not sure if this will work on stdClass or not, actually...)

Comment: I'm using a library for the OAuth and data retrieval, so yes I am getting it as json but the library converts it before I can ever touch it.

Comment: In that case, there's my edit!  Though Mike B's answer about `get_object_vars` is probably going to be more convenient for you.